# ¿Cómo genero un número aleatorio mayor al anterior ya generado?

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un programa que adivine una consonante PENSADA por el usuario y si no la acierta, que tenga otro intento pero hay que indicarle si es mayor o menor a la que nos ha dicho, hasta 5 intentos.

Aquí tengo el código que llevo el cual nos dice una consonante aleatoria y le podemos decir si ha acertado o no y al fallar el quinto intento, la máquina pierde pero me faltaría ponerle que cuando le diga que no ha acertado, que lo intente otra vez pero con una letra mayor o menor (alfabéticamente, por ejemplo la C es mayor que la B).

```
public static int adivinaConsonante() {
    int numConsonante, respuesta1, intentos = 1;
    boolean salir = false;

    String consonantes = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";

    Random random = new Random();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    do {
        numConsonante = random.nextInt(21);         

        System.out.println("¿Es la consonante " + consonantes.charAt(numConsonante) + "? (1:Sí / 2:No)");
        respuesta1 = keyboard.nextInt();

        if(respuesta1==1) {
            System.out.println("¡He ganado! Nos vemos en la siguiente partida");
            salir = true;
        }

        else if (respuesta1==2) {
            intentos++;
        }

     if(intentos==6) {
            System.out.println("He perdido, casi :(");
        }
    } while (!salir && intentos <= 5);


    return respuesta1;
}
```

Comment: Pequeño detalle, la i es una vocal. Te olvidaste de quitarla de `consonantes`

Comment: ¿Cuando te refieres a que la consonante sea mayor, te estás refiriendo a que por ejemplo c es mayor que b?

Comment: Gracias Mateo por el detalle, corregido y sí, me refiero a que la C es mayor que la B, lo edito en el post, gracias.

Comment: la respuesta que te marque como duplicada, no soluciona tu problema?